# PHP explode() must be of type string

Tags: php

I'm getting the average color of an image this way:

```
exec('magick "' . $tempCut . '" -resize 1x1\! -format "%[fx:int(255*r+.5)],%[fx:int(255*g+.5)],%[fx:int(255*b+.5)]" info:-', $col, $return_var);
file_put_contents($root . '/wth.txt', $col);
$arr = explode(',', $col);
```

`wth.txt` contains this string:

```
15,81,139
```

but explode gives the fatal error that it has to be a string, even though it is one??

What's wrong here and how to fix this?

Comment: Actually, `$col` could be an array, and file_put_contents is converting it. `You can also specify the data parameter as a single dimension array. This is equivalent to file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $array)).` Try `var_dump($col);` to see what it contains.

Comment: [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) ... `$col` (the output) would be an array

Comment: You are right it's a string array I needed to use it like: intval($col[0]), intval($col[1]), intval($col[2]) thanks! Give an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php exec output param is an array:

`If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().`

So, $col is an array and not a string. If you are sure that the string you are looking for is in the first line of output then following should work:

```
exec('magick "' . $tempCut . '" -resize 1x1\! -format "%[fx:int(255*r+.5)],%[fx:int(255*g+.5)],%[fx:int(255*b+.5)]" info:-', $col, $return_var);
file_put_contents($root . '/wth.txt', $col);
$arr = explode(',', $col[0]);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah it helps, you saved me times figuring out that the string is inside $col[0] :D Thanks